# Node Installation error

Tags: linux, node.js, redhat

I'm trying to install node.js from source on RH and I keep running into the below error.

```
make[1]: g++: Command not found
make[1]: *** [~/node-v0.10.20/out/Release/obj.target/v8_base/deps/v8/src/accessors.o] Error 127
```

Relevant Details:

I am attempting to install as a local user, without using the sudo command, by specifying the install path:

```
./configure --prefix=/path/to/node && make && make install
```

I've checked the dependencies listed, and I do have gcc 4.4, python 2.6.6 and gmake 3.8.1. It seems the make[1] commad is:

```
 g++ '-DENABLE_DEBUGGER_SUPPORT' '-DENABLE_EXTRA_CHECKS' '-DV8_TARGET_ARCH_X64' -I../deps/v8/src  -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -pthread -m64 -fno-strict -aliasing -O2 -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-tree-vrp -fno-tree-sink -fno-tree-vrp -fno-rtti -fno-exceptions -MMD -MF ~/node-v0.10.20/out/Release/.deps//var/opt/webdocs/wtprefork/ld/packages/node-v0.10.20/out/Release/obj.target/v8_base/deps/v8/src/accessors.o.d.raw  -c -o ~/node-v0.10.20/out/Release/obj.target/v8_base/deps/v8/src/accessors.o ../deps/v8/src/accessors.cc
```

Comment: What happens when you type `g++` into a console?

Comment: You need to install g++ ;-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're likely missing the gcc-c++ package.

Answer (score 3):

G++ is typically installed with GCC, but you can try to explicitly install G++ with `yum install gcc-c++`.

Comment: you are both correct, (i don't know about gcc bundling), so I gave you both an upvote, and chsh the check because he needs the rep more.